# How to Pass Static String Variable from One Controller to Muliple VF pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm working on Communities.
I have multiple VF pages like HomePage,ButtonPage and BusinessLogicPage and Its controllers like HomeController,ButtonController and So on.
I have created a VF Component as a Header. I include this Component to all my pages. 
My base VF (homePage) has a picklist.
These are ma Codes:

HomeController:

```
public with sharing class HomeController{
    public String selectedAccount{get;set;} 
    public static String selAcc;
    public HomeController() {}
    public PageReference go(){
            selAcc = selectedAccount;
            system.debug('STATIC**'+selAcc); // this is working fine. 
    }
    // code for AccountOptions here    
}
```

Home VF:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" controller="HomeController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<c:VECommunityHeaderComponent />
<apex:selectList id="organizationId" value="{!selectedAccount}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="box();">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
</apex:page>
```

ButtonController:

```
public with sharing class ButtonController{
    public static String selAcc;
    public ButtonController() {
        selAcc = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('orgId'); // OrgId is passed from URL from Home page
        //getSSA();
    }
}
```

Button VF:

```
<!-- I want to display it on the SectionHeader VF Component -->
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" controller="ButtonController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<c:VECommunityHeaderComponent />
</apex:page>
```

ComponentController

```
public with sharing class VECommunityHeaderController{
    public Pagereference p;   

    public string getheaderAccount() {
    // ^ when I give this Below Code, its working fine for HOME VF
        //return (HomeController.selAcc != null ) ? [Select Name from Account where Id =: HomeController.selAcc].Name : null;

    // Here I'm trying to choose my static String based on VF Page. 
    // This gives no answer. No errors
        if(p == Page.HomeVF){
            return (HomeController.selAcc != null ) ? [Select Name from Account where Id =: HomeController.selAcc].Name : null;
        }
        else if(p == Page.ButtonsVF){
            return (ButtonController.selAcc != null ) ? [Select Name from Account where Id =: ButtonController.selAcc].Name : null;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public VECommunityHeaderController() {}
}
```

ComponentVF:

```
<apex:component controller="VECommunityHeaderController">
<div class="loginInfo" style="width:200px;">
     <div class="row transparentBackground">
                <p><a href="javascript:void(0)">{!userFName} {!userLName}<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.VECommunity, 'VECommunity/images/dropdown.png')}"/></a></p>
                <p class="colorWhite">{!headerAccount}</p>                
     </div>
</div>  
</apex:component>
```

Please Assist

Comment: did u debug HomeController.selAcc in your component controller. what is orgId? is it the actual organization id that is being passed to the VF page?

Comment: yes I'm able to get the Static String value. Orgid is the Id that is passed in the URL from Home page to Buttons Page. That value i'm able to retrive with System.currentPagereference().getParameters() method.

Comment: You will never get anything returned, you are quering account object using org Id, the soql will always return blank.

Comment: Dude, I pass the required Account Id as a URL parameter to button page from home page when i choose a Select option on Home page and click the Go button. In the Button page controller i get that passed URL value of OrgId as SelAcc. Those things worked fine. not an issue with that.

Comment: Not being rude, but naming accountID as orgID and expecting us to understand your thought process is equally hard when it comes to solving questions on this forum

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your PageReference p before using it. Otherwise it will be null.

```
public VECommunityHeaderController() {
    p = ApexPages.currentPage();
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply use the below code:

```
if(HomeController.selAcc != null) {
    return [Select Name from Account where Id =: HomeController.selAcc].Name;
}
else if(ButtonController.selAcc != null) {
    return [Select Name from Account where Id =: ButtonController.selAcc].Name;
}
else {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding a Boolean static variable on all controllers and with same name and set it as true whenever OrgId is fetched. 
This is my latest `headerAccount()` method

```
public string getheaderAccount() {
    //return (VECommunityHome.selAcc != null ) ? [Select Name from Account where Id =: VECommunityHome.selAcc].Name : null;

    if(VECommunityHome.pageFlag == true){
    //if(p == Page.VEHome){
        system.debug('VEHOME'+VECommunityHome.pageFlag);
        return (VECommunityHome.selAcc != null ) ? [Select Name from Account where Id =: VECommunityHome.selAcc].Name : null;
    }

    if(VECommunityServiceTypeButtons.pageFlag == true){
    //else if(p == Page.VEServiceTypeButtons){
        system.debug('VEButton'+VECommunityServiceTypeButtons.pageFlag);
        return (VECommunityServiceTypeButtons.selAcc != null ) ? [Select Name from Account where Id =: VECommunityServiceTypeButtons.selAcc].Name : null;
    }

    if(VECommunityQuestionController.pageFlag == true){
    //else if(p == Page.VEServiceTypeButtons){
        system.debug('VEButton'+VECommunityQuestionController.pageFlag);
        return (VECommunityQuestionController.selAcc != null ) ? [Select Name from Account where Id =: VECommunityQuestionController.selAcc].Name : null;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: cleaner might be a super class for all controllers.  Controller constructor can set the value; also I think we got confused in that `orgId` in your use case is not the SFDC orgId